# Firebird conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql, firebird

Consider that I have a table named MYBOOKS consists of over a Million of rows of data.
I want to create a stored procedure to return a particular book if :BOOKID is provided, or, return all rows if :BOOKID is 0.

So here's the SQL that I came up with.

```
SELECT *
FROM MYBOOKS
WHERE :BOOKID = 0 OR BOOKID = :BOOKID
```

Let's say I want to find :BOOKID = 102.
This works, but it actually scans through millions of rows before returning just one row of data that I'm looking for. 
Is there a way to improve this SQL?

Please note that the illustration above has been simplified. 
In actual case, I have many more conditions in the WHERE clause and I want to make all of them OPTIONAL too.

```
SELECT *
FROM MYBOOKS
WHERE (:BOOKID = 0 OR BOOKID = :BOOKID) AND
      (:AUTHORID = 0 OR AUTHORID = :AUTHORID) AND
      (:TITLE = '' OR TITLE = :TITLE)
      //..... and so on
```

Is it possible to improve this SQL?
Thanks.

Comment: Add index to the fields you want to search on. Usually it's not best idea to create index for every collumn as this will slow down every change in the table but it's ok if you don't expect many changes.

Comment: The indexes have been created for the search fields but they didn't help. It seems that what slows it down is ":BOOKID = 0" part, it is evaluating that for each row.

Comment: Make sure you've created them for every field separately rather than for all at once. There should be a way to check if your query uses them or not but I don't remember much about FB.

Comment: Yes, all created separately.

Comment: Can't you just omit conditions equal 0 ?

Comment: It is used to check if parameter :BOOKID is given a value. If it is given a 0, means :BOOKID = 0 will evaluate to TRUE and therefore ignore the rule BOOKID = :BOOKID. Consider a typical search bar use case, where user can search for book title, author, id etc. They may or may not have values entered by user.

Comment: I see.. you can use `PLAN` to check if your indexes are used in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional `WHERE` is expensive. Firebird doesn't short circuit these kinds of evaluations and the optimizer is unable to select an optimal plan this way. It is probably better to generate the `WHERE` condition dynamically.

Other solutions include using a `UNION`, for example when you replace your first query with:

```
SELECT *
FROM MYBOOKS
WHERE BOOKID = :BOOKID
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM MYBOOKS
WHERE :BOOKID = 0
```

The optimizer usually chooses a better plan for this query, but given the multiple conditions you want to apply, this probably is not feasible.

Comment: So dynamic SQL is the better solution here? Is that what people usually do when they allow many fields to search/filter on?
Eg: Advance Searching on a forum

Comment: UNION does not help in this case.
-The execution plan is the same as the inital.

You can try something like this

<code>
SELECT B.*
FROM RDB$DATABASE
LEFT OUTER JOIN MYBOOKS P ON (1 = 1)
WHERE :BOOKID = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT B.*
FROM RDB$DATABASE
LEFT OUTER JOIN MYBOOKS B ON (B.BOOKID = :BOOKID)
WHERE :BOOKID <> 0
</code>

the execution plan is good but additional filtering conditions complicate things.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @tico Could be and I haven't tested it, I seem to remember it usually performs better though (on the other hand: dynamically deciding on the `WHERE` conditions is usually better.